# LoadError when pod install

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I run `pod install`, but it falls with error `LoadError - cannot load such file -- xcodeproj/prebuilt/x86_64-darwin12.5.0-2.0.0/xcodeproj_ext`

My environment:

```
   CocoaPods : 0.29.0
        Ruby : ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]
    RubyGems : 2.0.3
        Host : Mac OS X 10.9.1 (13B42)
       Xcode : 4.6.3 (4H1503)
Ruby lib dir : /Users/konstantinmakarychev/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 299f20b0909a26e46ffa381dcfc5b7fdd7dc2583
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solved my problem by myself:

```
:~$ gem update
:~$ gem pristine --all
:~$ gem install cocoapods
:~$ pod install
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this [Cocoapods Troubleshooting](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html). You should do this:

```
$ gem uninstall cocoapods
$ gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 1):

You should install the XCode Command line tools.

Comment: I have already installed Command Line Tools (with `xcode-select --install`)